# CiviEvent Dashboard not displaying all events

Tags: civievent, dashboard

Title pretty much sums it up - upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.8 and now the Event Dashboard only shows one event, although I have two active. Changing the number of displayed events under Administer>CiviEvent makes no difference.

Comment: Can you look in your database, find the id, title and start-date of your 2nd event and ensure that you can't use 'search' by date to find it?

Comment: The event shows up under Manage Events (?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/manage&reset=1), it doesn't appear in the Event Dashboard (?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event&reset=1)

Comment: For whatever it is worth, I have another Joomla 2.5x site for which this started happening after I updated to Civi 4.6.11.